# Counting letters in text node

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm making a virtual writer and I am having trouble counting the letters in a textnode inside a paragraph node.

Code looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Rfq68/
My problem is in the countLetters() function, I tried something like this:

```
var temp = ntext.match(new RegExp(search.toString().replace(/(?=[.\\+*?[^\]$(){}\|])/g, "\\"), "g"));
count = temp;
```

But it didn't work at all, and I need your help now!

Thanks!

Comment: How about `ntext.length`

Comment: I only want the letters, no spaces, comma, hyphens etc.

Comment: How about `ntext.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, '').length`

Comment: I tried that one aswell, when I click the count button nothing will load, compared to when I have nothing, then there will be an alert telling me there are no letters.

Comment: Oh, `ntext` is the text node. Then you'd have to use `return ntext.data.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, '').length;` ([fixed fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rfq68/1/))

Comment: Yea... I do that a lot lol.

Comment: No problem, bud. Also, always check your error console. You could have seen that error from the start *(that you were trying `.match()` on a node, not a string)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you attempt to use the `.match()` method on a node; only strings have that method.

Secondly, what I would do is get the text data from the node, replace all non-alphabetic characters, and then count them with the `.length` property available on all strings.

```
function countLetters() {
    return ntext.data.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, '').length;
}
```

---

[Fixed Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rfq68/1/)

Comment: Could `/[^a-z]/gi` be used?

Comment: Yeah. I just find the former to be more explicit, but both work the same.